# How can I enable the password eye in my ASP.NET webforms application?

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I maintain a VB ASP.NET webforms application.  For some reason the password eye does not show up in the field. I have confirmed it is enabled in my browser (Edge Chrome version), and I have also tested in Firefox.

Is there something I need to do to enable this feature (possibly in CSS?).  Here is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the web browser can do this. The template you use is also important. If it was an MVC project, maybe your input would be able to do this. Well, if you say how to do it right now. Follow ;

Place an icon inside or outside the input. Then update type whenever clicked.

[image]

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="current-password" name="password" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Şifre" class="sc-AxiKw feZyBA" value="123">
```

[image]

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="current-password" name="password" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Şifre" class="sc-AxiKw feZyBA" value="123">
```

Comment: Here is my site that I am having problems with, does anyone see the password eye?
https://pperc.illinoispoisoncenter.org/default.aspx

Comment: Thanks all, Guven I will try and implement your solution sounds like it may work!

Answer (score 0):

Quite sure this has nothing to do with the server side, or asp.net or IIS as a server.

You get that effect if you hit a Linux server.

So this is a browser and client side setting and option. And you can't mess with and change what the user has, what browser they are using, or even mess with THEIR settings and preferences. You can no more change this then what cute cat picture they have on their desktop.

In the new Chrome based Edge "IE" (which uses now the same engine as chrome based - it does not even use Microsofts own browser engine now!!!), you see this:

[image]

However, if you launch say FireFox, then you get this:

[image]

So all of these little "things" that browser vendors like and have?

I don't think you can control these thing a ma do's that appear?

Like the "key" in FireFox, or the all seeing and knowing "eye" in the new Edge browser?

In Edge I get this:

[image]

But in the Edge developer version I get this:

[image]

So, you quite much see and get as many different behaviors as there are different browsers in existing. This will depend on the browser you use, and in fact EVEN the version of the browser from a given browser vendor. So the combinations and permutations are not only endless here? But they are something out of your control for the most part.